# Assembly move instruction seems to be useless

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly, instructions

I'am trying to learn assembly. I disassembled a simple C program and debugged it with gdb. But one thing I've noticed is that values are moved very frequent.

```
   0x0000555555555231 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x0000555555555232 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000555555555235 <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x20

   0x0000555555555239 <+8>:     mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rdi
   0x000055555555523d <+12>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rsi
   0x0000555555555241 <+16>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x0000555555555245 <+20>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000555555555248 <+23>:    call   0x5555555551d9 <get_file_size>
```

rdi's value gets moved to the stack at rbp-0x18 (at <+8>), rsi's value to the stack at rbp-0x20 (+12). Then the value at rbp-0x18 gets moved to rax(+16) which will be moved to rdi again(+20). Why is this done? Why not just using rdi or at least moving rbp-0x18 to rdi directly instead via rax (at <+16>)? This could save the instruction at +20

Comment: Try enabling optimization when you compile.  With `gcc`, try specifying `-O3` and see what you get.

Comment: I use https://godbolt.org/ to see difference between code and optimization, this can help you

Comment: it is preserving the incoming parameters on the stack (for later use or if unoptimized then just because it is part of a basic construction of the function) and then a nested call is being made using one of the parameters, since that parameter lives on the stack (unoptimized) it needs to read it from the stack.  the pushes and the call are two separate sub constructions within the building of the function.  stack frame, then save parameters, then make a call, three separate things are represented here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compilation without any optimisations enabled does not have to much sense if you want to learn some assembler from it.

Here you have an example how the optimizations can change the generated code.

https://godbolt.org/z/YBdLRZ

```
char *foo(char *dest, const char *src, size_t len)
{
    char *savedDest = dest;
    size_t index = 0;
    if(len)
    {
        while(--len && (dest[index] = src[index]));
        index++;
        *dest = 0;
    }
    return savedDest;
}
```

No optimizations

```
foo:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rsi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], rdx
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], 0
        je      .L2
.L4:
        sub     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], 1
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], 0
        je      .L3
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        add     rdx, rax
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        add     rax, rcx
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rdx]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax], dl
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
        test    al, al
        jne     .L4
.L3:
        add     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], 1
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax], 0
.L2:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

and optimize of size

```
foo:
        mov     rax, rdi
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L2
.L4:
        dec     rdx
        je      .L3
        mov     cl, BYTE PTR [rsi]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax], cl
        test    cl, cl
        jne     .L4
.L3:
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax], 0
.L2:
        ret
```

Comment: I think that there's an extra `;` at the end of the while loop that makes the optimization very easy isn't?

Comment: no - https://godbolt.org/z/vunc6o